# How to properly handle useStates and useEffects in a Reactjs simple quiz app that is rendering everything twice?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building this simple quiz app in React where a random Korean hangul from a 40-item `Data.json` is displayed on the screen and users have 5 buttons with different answers which also come from `Data.json`.

For clarification, this is my application and the components I'm using. All components are siblings and live inside `App.js`.

[image: Application screenshot]

What the application is suppose to do is to create a 5-item random array and select one of these as the right answer before render. If the user taps the right button all the components should be re-rendered with different items. That's why I decided to use the `useEffect()` hook.

But what is currently happening is:

- Every `console.log` is being displayed twice in the console. The first time variables are empty and in the second time they display the values they should have;
- The randomOptions array has 10 items instead of 5;
- If the `<Question/>` component is in the code then I get errors and `console.log` tells me the values from my `useState` hooks are undefined. If `<Question/>` is removed I get the console shown in the picture below.

Console for clarification:

[image: Application Console]

`App.js` component:

```
import './App.css';
import Data from './data/data.json';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Question from './components/Question';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)); // Tells us what the index of the right answer is
  const [randomOptions, setRandomOptions] = useState([]); // Random array with 5 items from Data.json that are the options
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState([]); // The question that goes to <Question/> and people need to guess

  const randomizeButtonAnswer = () => {
    let previousArray = randomOptions;
    setRandomOptions([]);
      for (let i=0; i < 5; i++){
        let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * Data.length); 
          if (!randomOptions.includes(randomNumber) && !previousArray.includes(randomNumber)) {
            setRandomOptions(randomOptions.push(randomNumber)); 
          } else {
            i--;
          }
        }
      setRandomOptions(randomOptions.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5));
      setQuestion(randomOptions[index]);
    }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    randomizeButtonAnswer();
  }, [index])

  console.log('index is ' + index); // 3
  console.log('randomOptions is ' + randomOptions); // 33,9,3,26,8,20,0,12,29,25
  console.log('question is ' + question); //26

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Question answer={question}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`Question.js` component

```
import './Question.css';
import Data from '../data/data.json';

const Question = ({ answer }) => {

    return (
        <div className="question-wrapper">
            <h1 className="question"><span className="highlight">{Data[answer].character}</span></h1>
                <span>{Data[answer].character} = {Data[answer].char_id} </span>
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default Question;
```

I'm completely lost here. Not sure why things are being rendered twice or why when present `<Question/>` makes my variables become undefined. I assume something inside `randomizeButtonAnswer` is broken but I've been unable to find what exactly.

Small disclaimer: I'm a complete noob to React so if I'm doing something that is wrong or a bad practice do let me know.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Does your app wrapped by `<StrictMode >` ? **StrictMode** component in React does render component twice. Clear it if you had it (you will have it if you created from template). Check  `index.js`

Comment: @TakashiAnji, wow that was it. My array has now 5 items instead of 10 and things are not being rendered twice. I'll definitely read more about `<StrictMode>`. But adding  `<Question/>` to the `App.js` component still make all variables undefined. Any idea of what could be causing this weird behavior?

Comment: Hey, Could you please add a codesandbox ? Sorry, it quite late now. I will check and answer you tomorrow

Comment: Yeah, of course. Here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-feather-zj8wyf?file=/src/App.js . Notice that values are fine until you uncomment `<Question/>`. Now I also think the line `setRandomOptions([])` is not reseting the `randomOptions` before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to fix your code but it's complicated and wrong at many points so I decided to write the function myself. Sorry about that.

[Here is the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-glade-kw4qcb?file=/src/App.js)

there are many problem with your code.

1. About log 2 times. It is `<StrictMode />`
2. You should understand more about React State. It not change right in the place you write it, it's **queue up** and update when your functions end. set 1 state 2 time in 1 function does not mean anything.
3. Don't do `i--` in for loop like that which is complicated to understand how things goes and hard to debug. use while loop or for best just `don't`. check the condition and log out or have some handle for it.
4. Wanna log? log inside React Component? use `useEffect`.
5. Default state of Question is not [].
6. Always do conditional render if default value of state is possible be either `null` or `undefined`.

Good luck with your React journey.

Comment: You presented me with lots of learning opportunities and as someone just getting started this is priceless. I'll study your code and the topics you mentioned. I really appreciate the time you took to help. Thank you so much for your help!